# Twitter streaming api - get comments

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to get all tweets and comments related to specific topic by it's hashtag. I am able to use streaming API to get every new tweet with that hashtag, but my question is, if it is somehow possible to fetch also comments to those tweets? It doesn't need to be streaming API, but in REST API I can't find it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter currently doesn't allow you to get replies to a specific tweet.  The best you can do is a search for `@username` and filter that by `in_reply_to`.