# Sentiment Analysis for Twitter with Python (separating queries from the rest of tweets)

Tags: python, twitter, analytics, sentiment-analysis, twint

I'm doing some sentiment analysis for my organisation using Python. I'm trying to find a way to separate queries that are raised by people from the rest of the tweets associated with the organisation twitter handles. Is there a way to go about doing that? If anyone can be of assistance I would be grateful.

Comment: you want to track a Twitter handle's tweets?

Comment: @Darkknight I have managed to set up a pipeline to stream the tweets for a handle I'm interested in. I want to now separate the queries that people make. Which would include the comments people make in regards to the brand of the handle.

Comment: @Robin1005 currently there is no way to extract the comment for a particular tweet. For more info refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506162/twitter-streaming-api-get-comments